# More elegant way for updating a slice of a list

Tags: list, iteration, python

Given a list, I would like to apply some set of operations to a subset(slice) of the list, and store the result of each transformation in the original list.

My background is in Ada, which led me to make the following mistake:

```
Number_List = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
for Index, Number in enumerate(Number_List[1:]):
  Number_List[Index] = Number + 1
```

Giving a new Number_List of: 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,9 and teaching me that a slice of an array is re-indexed to 0.

I've moved to the following, which is cumbersome but functional.

```
Number_List = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
for Index in range(1,len(Number_List))
  Number_List[Index] = Number_List[Index]+1
```

I am looking for a more elegant way to do this.

Comment: Thanks for the tag updates.  I love that there is a 'pythonic' tag.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`enumerate` takes a `start` parameter:

```
Number_List = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
for Index, Number in enumerate(Number_List[1:], start=1):
  Number_List[Index] = Number + 1
```

You can also write

```
Number_List[1:] = [x+1 for x in Number_List[1:]]
```

Comment: I prefer the second example, but for more complicated operations I could see it becoming confusing.

Answer (score 1):

```
from itertools import islice
number_list[start:stop] = (x + 1 for x in islice(number_list, start, stop))
```

Alternatively, use `number_list[start:stop]` instead of `islice`, but that creates another slice needlessly. This updates the list in-places either way thanks to slice assignment and avoids an explicit loop.

Answer (score 1):

You can use list comprehensions and slices to great effect:

```
vals = range(10) #gives your example numbers
vals[1:] = [v + 1 for v in vals[1:]]
```